# On provability of Paris–Harrington theorem

Tags: logic, provability

It is said that the Paris–Harrington theorem is true, but not provable in Peano arithmetic. I want to ask: So how do they know that it is true if it has no proof? I cannot imagine someone knows something is true but cannot explain why?

I think a proof has a definition for a theory like Peano arithmetic, probably it is a sequence of propositions satisfying some metalanguage rules‎! (is it correct?). So there is not any proof for Paris–Harrington theorem with this definition. But there is some proof (defined somehow else). There doesn't seem to be a way to know something without a convincing proof‎! Is there?

Comment: It is provable in ZF, indeed much less.

Comment: So it is true for someone who accepts ZF premises; but it is independent if someone just accepts Peano arithmetic premises?

Comment: Yes : "... but not provable in Peano arithmetic" means exactly that you cannot prove it if you assume **only** the axioms of Peano's arithmetic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Does "... but not provable in Peano arithmetic" mean the the theorem is *independent*: niether true nor false in Peano theory?

Comment: A statement cannot be "true" or "false" in a theory; it can only be "true" or "false" in a model. A statement can be provable, or unprovable, in a theory. @user795571

Comment: @CarlMummert: Is there a difference between a theory and a model? Can you give me an example for each one?

Comment: Peano Arithmetic is a theory. The set of natural numbers is a model of Peano Arithmetic. There are many other models of Peano Arithmetic, as well. It makes sense to ask whether a sentence is true in a model, but not to ask whether it is "true in a theory"; the right question is whether it is provable in the theory. @user795571

Comment: @CarlMummert Do you mean a model of a theory $A$ is a construction in another theory $B$ satisfying the axioms of $A$? Because the set of natural numbers is  constructed in set theory.

Comment: Do not confuse "Peano Arithmetic" with that usual arithmetic based on set theory and the five Peano axioms defining N, S and 0 (or 1). I understand that PH can be proven in the latter. See http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sacook/csc438h/notes/page96.pdf

Answer (score 9):

First, a bit of terminology. There is a particular combinatorial result, a strengthened form of Ramsey's theorem. That result is provable in many systems, including ZF set theory. Let's call this combinatorial result $R$. The Paris-Harrington theorem shows that result $R$ is not provable in Peano Arithmetic. In what I believe is the most common terminology in the field, the result $R$ itself is not the "Paris-Harrington theorem".

Now, $R$ cannot be disprovable in Peano Arithmetic, because then it would be disprovable in ZF as well. But $R$ is provable in ZF, and ZF is consistent.

Keep in mind that most ordinary mathematical proofs are not written in *any* formal system: they are just written in natural language using accepted methods of reasoning.

---

As a side note, the Paris-Harrington theorem *itself* is unprovable in Peano arithmetic, but for a trivial reason: the Paris-Harrington theorem states that $R$ is unprovable in Peano Arithmetic, and because of the incompleteness theorem Peano Arithmetic cannot prove that *any* theorem is unprovable in itself. Peano Arithmetic cannot even prove that "1 + 1 = 3 is unprovable in Peano Arithmetic", much less that $R$ is unprovable.

What Paris and Harrington actually showed is that $R$ implies, within PA, the consistency of PA. Therefore, by the incompleteness theorem, $R$ cannot be provable in PA.

Comment: Does PA+Con(PA) prove the Paris-Harrington theorem?

Comment: For concreteness, the combinatorial result $R$ I mentioned is Theorem 1.2 in the paper by Paris and Harrington in the *Handbook of Mathematical Logic*. In that paper, they show that $R$ is equivalent over PA to a principle known as $\Sigma^0_1$ reflection, which says that "for each $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence $\phi$, if PA proves $\phi$ then $\phi$".  This reflection principle is slightly stronger than Con(PA), but implies Con(PA). So the exact strength of $R$ is known.

Comment: I've heard it said (e.g. by Slaman) that PH is an example of infinitary methods being necessary to prove finitary statements. I guess that imples that $\Sigma^{0}_{1}$ reflection should count as "infinitary means". True? What exactly is infinitary about that?

Comment: Addendum to my last comment: I guess that if PA is supposed to capture "finitary means", then adding any statement unprovable from PA but true should count as using "infinitary methods". I'm trying to understand if it's possible to "see the infinity" beyond merely seeing that more than PA has been used.

Comment: @Quinn Culver: in this case, the "standard" proof shows that the Paris--Harrington principle is equivalent over PA to transfinite induction  up to $\epsilon_0$ for some class of formulas.  So saying that PH requires infinitary methods may just mean that any axioms that prove PH will also prove that form of transfinite induction.    In particular, the reflection principle implies more transfinite induction than PA on its own.

Comment: One thing about the reflection principle is that it seem challenging to give a finitistic justification for it - reflection follows from the soundness theorem, but that theorem refers to models, and so it does not seem to be stated in finitary terms.  If we try to avoid talking about models, then we seem to be led to justify reflection by some kind of induction on the structure of the derivation, but that leads immediately back to the connection with transfinite induction.